# How to prove that this determinant is zero by MMA?

Tags: matrix

Say,

$\boldsymbol{A}^2=\boldsymbol{I}$,
$\boldsymbol{B}^2=\boldsymbol{I}$,
$|\boldsymbol{A}|+|\boldsymbol{B}|=0$,

to prove,

$|\boldsymbol{A}+\boldsymbol{B}|=0,and  |\boldsymbol{I}+\boldsymbol{A B}|=0$

here is my code,

```
Clear["Global`*"];
mA = Array[a, {3, 3}];
mB = Array[b, {3, 3}];
mI3 = IdentityMatrix[3];
detmApdetmB = Det[mA] + Det[mB];
detmApmB = Det[mA + mB];
detmIpAB = Det[mI3 + mA . mB];
listmA = Flatten[mA];
listmB = Flatten[mB];
listmAmB = Flatten[{listmA, listmB}];
statement = detmApmB == 0;

Assuming[MatrixPower[mA, 2] == mI3 && MatrixPower[mB, 2] == mI3 && 
  detmApdetmB == 0, 
 Refine[Reduce[$Assumptions && statement, listmAmB, Reals]]]
```

> $Aborted

```
Clear["Global`*"];
mA = Array[a, {3, 3}];
mB = Array[b, {3, 3}];
mI3 = IdentityMatrix[3];
detmApdetmB = Det[mA] + Det[mB];
detmApmB = Det[mA + mB];
detmIpAB = Det[mI3 + mA . mB];
listmA = Flatten[mA];
listmB = Flatten[mB];
listmAmB = Flatten[{listmA, listmB}];
statement = detmApmB == 0;

Assuming[MatrixPower[mA, 2] == mI3 && MatrixPower[mB, 2] == mI3 && 
  detmIpAB == 0, 
 Refine[Reduce[$Assumptions && statement, listmAmB, Reals]]]
```

> $Aborted

**EDIT**

Thanks for @ user64494's answer. The code runs very fast. I tried to prove my question with `FindInstance` before, but the code has been running without results. After reading the answer to @ user64494, I checked my code again and found a problem. ***In my code, whether to restrict the `Reals` field in `FindInstance` has a great impact on the running results. The @ user64494 code has no this effect. Does anyone know why?***

***my code:***

```
Clear["Global`*"];
mA = Array[a, {3, 3}];
mB = Array[b, {3, 3}];
mI3 = IdentityMatrix[3];
detmApdetmB = Det[mA] + Det[mB];
detmApmB = Det[mA + mB];
listmA = Flatten[mA];
listmB = Flatten[mB];
listmAmB = Flatten[{listmA, listmB}];
FindInstance[
 detmApmB != 0 && MatrixPower[mA, 2] == mI3 && 
  MatrixPower[mB, 2] == mI3 && detmApdetmB == 0, listmAmB, Reals]
```

> $Aborted

```
Clear["Global`*"];
mA = Array[a, {3, 3}];
mB = Array[b, {3, 3}];
mI3 = IdentityMatrix[3];
detmApdetmB = Det[mA] + Det[mB];
detmApmB = Det[mA + mB];
listmA = Flatten[mA];
listmB = Flatten[mB];
listmAmB = Flatten[{listmA, listmB}];
FindInstance[
 detmApmB != 0 && MatrixPower[mA, 2] == mI3 && 
  MatrixPower[mB, 2] == mI3 && detmApdetmB == 0, listmAmB]
```

> {}

***@user64494's code:***

```
Clear["Global`*"];
mA = Array[a, {3, 3}];
mB = Array[b, {3, 3}];
mI3 = IdentityMatrix[3];
FindInstance[
 Det[mA + mB] != 0 && mA^2 == mI3 && mB^2 == mI3 && 
  Det[mA] + Det[mB] == 0, Flatten[{Flatten[mA], Flatten[mB]}]]
```

> {}

```
Clear["Global`*"];
mA = Array[a, {3, 3}];
mB = Array[b, {3, 3}];
mI3 = IdentityMatrix[3];
FindInstance[
 Det[mA + mB] != 0 && mA^2 == mI3 && mB^2 == mI3 && 
  Det[mA] + Det[mB] == 0, Flatten[{Flatten[mA], Flatten[mB]}], Reals]
```

> {}

Comment: Something to adjust: the LHS of $\boldsymbol{A}+\boldsymbol{B}=0$ is a matrix, but its RHS is a number.

Comment: Sorry, there are some typos in my question. See my edit. @user64494

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your claim is not true. Here is a simple counterexample.

```
a = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
b = {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}};
b.b
```

> `{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}`

```
Det[a] + Det[b]
```

> `0`

```
a+b
```

> `{{0, 0}, {0, 2}}`

Addition. If you mean $|mA+mB|=0$ as your claim, then the following does the job in three dimensions.

```
Clear["Global`*"];mA = Array[a, {3, 3}];mB = Array[b, {3, 3}];
mI3 = IdentityMatrix[3];
FindInstance[Det[mA + mB] != 0 && mA^2 == mI3 && mB^2 == mI3 && Det[mA] +
Det[mB] == 0,  Flatten[{Table[a[i, j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}], 
Table[b[i, j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]}]]
```

> `{}`

Comment: Why 'Det[mA]==0 && Det[mB]==0'？

Comment: Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: `FindInstance[
 Det[mI3 + mA . mB] != 0 && mA^2 == mI3 && mB^2 == mI3 && 
  Det[mA] + Det[mB] == 0, 
 Flatten[{Table[a[i, j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}], 
   Table[b[i, j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]}]]`  results in `{}` and answers your second question.

Comment: Thank you! See my second edit. @user64494